# Finding the (x,y) value of a figure

Tags: plotting

How do I find the point where the graph cuts x axis (function is zero). I am not familiar with Mathematica plotting. In Matlab, I can use the "data cursor" and move it along the curve to find the point that gives the y value when x is 0. Can a similar thing be done in Mathematica?

[image]

Comment: Where is the plot from? Did you generate it? If so, can you just evaluate the function (or the `Limit`) at 0, or use `Solve` if it's in terms of y?

Comment: @eyorble I tried using `Solve`. But its a complex function and Mathematica didn't produce an output although I let it run fro a very long time.

Comment: Perhaps `FindRoot` or `NSolve` would be more useful then. Since you have the graph already, using `FindRoot` to find the visible roots near 320000 and 1.8*10^6 should work better than `Solve` usually will with complex graphs.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GetCoordinatesForPointsInAPlot.html

Comment: @eyorble Thank you so much. `FindRoot` solved the problem. Do you know why `Solve` can't find the solution but `FindRoot` can?

Comment: `Solve` prefers to use algebraic methods when possible, but for complex functions algebraic solutions may not exist (even in terms of special functions). `FindRoot` simply uses numerical root finding methods, like Newton's method, to find the answers, so it is much less dependent on the actual form of the equation. The trade off is that `FindRoot` can only find one answer at a time, and it can never find exact answers.

Comment: @eyorble But when I plug in the value that I get from `FindRoot`  to my function it doesn't produce 0. What it gives is a very small value like $-2*10^{-11}$. Is it because of a numerical error?

Comment: Yes. As noted, `FindRoot` does not find exact values, so it's entirely possible that numerical error will creep in during calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` to show the points on the x-axis

```
plt = Plot[ Sin[x] + x Cos[x], {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[.03]]]
```

[image]

and post-process the `Plot` output to add `Tooltip`s to `Point`s:

```
Normal[plt] /. Point[x_] :> Tooltip[Point[x], x[[1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so  much for the answer. So the line `Normal[plt] /. Point[x_] :> Tooltip[Point[x], x[[1]]] ` only gives the points where it cuts the x axis right?

Comment: @sam_rox, yes, tooltip shows the x coordinates where y=0.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you want to find coordinates by using mouse cursor, for this i have attached code for simple graph of sin(x). you can add your graph in graphics option and can get your desired coordinates by using code
   `{Graphics[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]], Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics"]]}`
hope you get what you want

Comment: or you can also use the from the top of your mathematica screen Graphics>Tools>Get Coordinates(last option)